# Execute input after time

Tags: codeigniter

I have a search module in a page made with codeigniter. The search goes off automatically just after the first entry. How can i trigger the search after the user stop key in ?

```
<?php 
      $attributes = array("class" => "form-horizontal", "id" => "search", "name" => "search");
      echo form_open("secret_cont/search", $attributes);?>

 <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search a student by name" id="search" oninput="document.forms.search.submit();"/>
<input type='submit' value='Ok' />

<?=form_close();?>
```

Thanks !

Comment: I think you should use AJAX for this. Using ajax you can call a php controller with every input change and display the result back using JS without the need for form submit

Comment: Thanks so much for the idea. An exemple would help so much !

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp